# Merge 1000 HTML files in R

Tags: r, merge, htmlwidgets

I have more than 1000 html files and I want to merge them together. I have provided the code below how I am doing it. But it's not getting merge and I am getting blank html file(merged).

```
saveWidget(f1, "f1.html")
saveWidget(f2, "f2.html")
saveWidget(f3, "f3.html")
saveWidget(f4, "f4.html") and so on till saveWidget(f1000, "f1000.html")
```

Code to merge files:

```
    library(htmlwidgets)
    htmlFiles<-list.files("/path/")
    library(htmltools)
    widgets <- list(htmlFiles)
    #fns <- replicate(length(widgets), tempfile(pattern = "widget_", fileext = #".html"))
    #Map(htmlwidgets::saveWidget, widgets, fns)

iframes <- lapply(widgets, function(fn) 
  tags$iframe(
    src = paste0("/path/", fn), 
    style="display:block", 
    height="300", width="1200"
  )  
)
tags$html(
  tags$body(
    iframes
  )
) %>% 
  save_html(tf<<-tempfile(fileext = ".html"))
shell.exec(tf)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you forget to add `library(htmlwidgets)`? If not, then where is `saveWidget` defined?

Comment: Hey sorry, I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
library(htmltools)
widgets <- list(DT::datatable(mtcars), DT::datatable(USArrests))
fns <- replicate(length(widgets), tempfile(pattern = "widget_", fileext = ".html"))
Map(htmlwidgets::saveWidget, widgets, fns)

iframes <- lapply(fns, function(fn) 
  tags$iframe(
    src = paste0("file:///", fn), 
    style="display:block", 
    height="300", width="1200"
  )  
)
tags$html(
  tags$body(
    iframes
  )
) %>% 
  save_html(tf<<-tempfile(fileext = ".html"))
shell.exec(tf)
```

[image]

Comment: Can i use in the following way? `library(htmltools)
widgets <- htmlFiles
fns <- replicate(length(widgets), tempfile(pattern = "widget_", fileext = ".html"))
Map(htmlwidgets::saveWidget, widgets, fns)`

Comment: @user15051990 No. Use `widgets <- mget(ls(pattern = "^f\\d+$"))`