# Merge html files in R with filenames as headings

Tags: html, r

I am able to merge a bunch of html files in R thanks to the helpful answer from @lukeA in:
[Merge 1000 HTML files in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50762229/merge-1000-html-files-in-r)

Each of my html files contains the address of just one PNG image file. When I merge them, I get a new html file that displays each image successively down the page.  Just what I wanted... but...

I would like to add the filename/address at the top of each image.  I think I could use `h1()` in the `tags$iframe` somehow, but would I need to rewrite the whole thing using a for-loop instead of `lapply()`?  I have not messed about with html before - all help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to wrap a `tags$h1()` alongside the iframe part within a div element:

```
iframes <- lapply(fns, function(fn) 
  tags$div(
    tags$h1(paste0("file:///", fn)),
    tags$iframe(
      src = paste0("file:///", fn), 
      style="display:block", 
      height="300", width="1200"
    )  
  )
)
```

(Expanding on the linked thread to add new tag)

Though it might be better to extract the img source from each file using `rvest` and with the html tags construct a new page with new img tags to display all images (using some sample pages here, but you would pass a vector of file names)

```
library(htmltools)
library(rvest)

pages <- c("<html><body><img src='https://www.r-project.org/Rlogo.png'></body></html>",
           "<html><body><img src='https://p.kindpng.com/picc/s/160-1607808_stock-investing-insights-and-information-stocks-png-transparent.png'></body></html>")

images <- lapply(pages, function(page){
  
  img_src <- read_html(page) %>% 
    html_node("img") %>% 
    html_attr("src")
  
  tags$div(
    tags$h1(img_src),
    tags$img(src = img_src)
  )
}

)

tags$html(
  tags$body(
    images
  )
)
```

Returns:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <h1>https://www.r-project.org/Rlogo.png</h1>
      <img src="https://www.r-project.org/Rlogo.png"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h1>https://p.kindpng.com/picc/s/160-1607808_stock-investing-insights-and-information-stocks-png-transparent.png</h1>
      <img src="https://p.kindpng.com/picc/s/160-1607808_stock-investing-insights-and-information-stocks-png-transparent.png"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Do let me know if there are problems that come back from that - can't quite test out on your data.

Comment: thank you so much, I will extract myself from a rabbit hole and give this a try on my data.

Comment: Thanks again - the first solution worked for my data.  I also tried the second solution, but it did not work on my data because my ```pages``` object is simply a list of html files. Much appreciated.